# Lambda Javascript Function Fails to Access EFS-Copied Dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-efs, aws-policies

I've created a Javascript Lambda function that relies on dependencies from two substantial modules, namely u/aws-sdk and u/asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core. To make these dependencies accessible, I mounted an Amazon Elastic File System (EFS) from the EC2 command line and copied the modules using these commands:

```bash
sudo cp -r extracted-packages/@aws-sdk /mnt/efs/

sudo cp -r extracted-packages/node-fhir-server-core /mnt/efs/
```

While I can confirm that I can see the contents of these directories by running `cd /mnt/efs/`
, `ls -l u/aws-sdk`, and `ls -l node-fhir-server-core` within the EC2 instance, I'm encountering an issue. These directories are not visible in the EFS console. I suspect this discrepancy is causing the "Cannot find module '@asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core'" error I encountered when I deployed my functions and executed a test event to post a patient within the Lambda console. .

I've associated an inline policy with the Lambda function, granting it permissions to mount and write to the Elastic File System (EFS). The Lambda function is configured to run within a VPC, ensuring access to the EFS. Additionally, there is an attached EC2 policy that includes actions related to network interfaces, such as creating, describing, and deleting them.

However, when I attempt to execute a test post using an event JSON like this:

```json
{
  "body": "{\"base_version\":\"R4\",\"resource\":{\"given\":\"John\",\"family\":\"Doe\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"birthDate\":\"1990-01-15\"}}"
}
```

I encounter an issue. Instead of the expected data, I receive the error message: 'Cannot find module '@asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core'.

Comment: Note that you can make use of docker containers in Lambda and the maximum size of a docker image is 10GB.

Comment: How are you importing these packages? Did you try to do it by providing full path to the them? Do you "see" them from Lambda function? You can try to check by runnning `ls -la <path>` with `spawn` for example.